# How do I define properties orientation in a 2D short random fibers composite? ABAQUS

Tags: abaqus, composite

I generated different 2D microstructures with different fibers volumetric fraction (basically a square representing the matrix and a lot of small rectangles inside, with different measures and random orientations, representing the fibers). I'm attaching a figure to be clearer.
[image]To run the simulations using Abaqus I need to define the properties of the fibers (the rectangles), but how do I set the properties according to the main axis of each fibers considering that I have random orientations? I cannot manually set the axis orientations for each fiber, it would be too timeconsuming considering that I have configurations with 40% of fibers (more than 400). I need to find a way to set the properties according to the main axis of the fibers (rectangles).
To be more specific, I created an RSA alghoritm in Matlab to create the random distribution of fibers. Then, I create the main square (representing the matrix of the composite) in Abaqus and I create the fibers by partion, importing the generated fibers distribution as a sketch.
Thank you all for your attention.